# Can you control how Selenium IDE references elements?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have started using Selenium IDE.  I am recording my actions to create tests.

My problem is that it prefers to reference elements by id, but I am using Stripes framework and that tends to give widgets random id's.

So is there a way to get it to prefer another way to reference an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Selenium IDE, if you go to Options -> Options..., you can specify the ordering of the locator builders that the ide will use.  Here's a screenshot below: [image]
Then you can just change the ordering to put id near the bottom if the id is randomly generated.